# Python - unpacking a list of nametuples

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension, psutil

I am using psutil.users() to get a list of namedtuples referencing each user on the system.  I am trying to make a dictionary of just the names and terminal types and I am junking the rest.  When I do this:

```
{user.name:user.terminal for user in psutil.users()}
```

I only get one of the users, not both.  I know there are two there because I can print psutil.users() and see them both.  I couldn't see what I was doing wrong so I did:

```
for user in psutil.users():
    print user.name
    print user.terminal
```

and it works just as intended.  But my dict comprehension version doesn't.  I can't see what I'm doing incorrectly.

Comment: make sure each time, user.name is unique. It may be possible that there is only one unique key in your case.

Comment: Gah, you're correct -- I forgot that both the users are named the same (different terminal types, though).  It was so simple I couldn't see it ;)  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, it may be possible that both username is same and in dictionary we are required to have unique key. That is why you are getting only one key-value pair in your code.